# How to Find Execution Time and Memory usage of a program in c

Tags: c

I have made a application program in c language. And now i am trying to find Execution time and memory usage of my program. I have tried using time.h header and had done following 
dif_sec = (double) difftime (time2,time1);
But every time i run the program, it give different execution time.
For eg. : 1st time i got 19 millisecond, and if i again i run the same program it will give me different execution time, greater then 19 millisecond, around 28 millisecond. And some time it give around 150 millisecond. So i am trying to get perfect execution time.
And also need a help to find memory usage of a program.
I am running my program on CodeBlocks in windows.

Comment: if you're on *nix try `time(1)` http://linux.die.net/man/1/time

Comment: Use a profiler (like valgrind for linux / unix); you'll get much more exact results than with manual timing.

Comment: See `getrusage(2)` as well

Comment: It is operating system specific. You should have tagged your question with *Windows* ...

Answer (score 0):

For Windows programs you can use QueryPerformanceCounter and QueryPerformanceFrequency to measure times to a decent accuracy. There's an article [here](http://bobmoore.mvps.org/Win32/w32tip65.htm).